# WPS412 Found `__init__.py` module with logic

Tags: python, python-3.x, flake8, wemake-python-style-guide

For my package named "finding_hidden_messages_in_dna", I have a `__init__.py` file whose contents are as follows:

```
"""summary line: finding_hidden_messages_in_dna is a subpackage.

**description**
It is the part of package coursera_bioinformatics_specialization_solutions.
"""

from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.approximate_occurrences_of_pattern_with_given_hamming_distance import \
    find_all_approximate_occurrences_of_pattern_with_given_hamming_distance_in_text
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.clumps_in_text import find_clumps_in_text
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.dnaa_box_based_on_mismatches_and_reverse_complements import \
    find_dnaa_box_based_on_mismatches_and_reverse_complements
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.frequency_table import \
    generate_frequency_table
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.hamming_distance import \
    find_hamming_distance
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.kmp import kmp
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.kmp_find_all_Occurrences import \
    find_all_occurrences_of_pattern_in_text
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.locations_of_minimum_and_maximum_skew_value import \
    find_locations_of_minimum_and_maximum_skew_value
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.longest_prefix_that_is_also_suffix import \
    longest_prefix_that_is_also_suffix
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.most_frequent_k_mers_and_respective_reverse_complements_with_mismatches import \
    find_most_frequent_k_mers_and_respective_reverse_complements_with_mismatches
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.most_frequent_k_mers_in_text import \
    find_all_most_frequent_k_mers
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.most_frequent_k_mers_with_mismatches import \
    find_most_frequent_k_mers_with_mismatches
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.neighbors import \
    find_neighbors_with_expected_hamming_distance
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.reverse_complement import \
    find_reverse_complement
from finding_hidden_messages_in_dna.skew_value import find_skew_value
```

**Question:** When I run `flake8` on this file, I got the following error:

> WPS412 Found `__init__.py` module with logic

I cannot understand, where did I put any logic in this file?

Answer (score 3):

[documentation](https://wemake-python-stylegui.de/en/latest/pages/usage/violations/best_practices.html#wemake_python_styleguide.violations.best_practices.InitModuleHasLogicViolation)

WPS412 forbids *all* code in `__init__.py` (minus a single docstring), including imports.

you can of course disable this rule with `extend-ignore` or `per-file-ignores`, though personally I think this is a good rule

---

disclaimer: I'm the current flake8 maintainer, though unaffiliated with WPS